# Can't run qt commands like qtviewer

Tags: qt

I am new to Qt so I follow a tutorial on QML. It starts with a basic qml file which should be run with `qmlviewer`.

The problem is that when I start `qmlviewer` it says

`qmlviewer: could not exec '/usr/lib/qt/bin/qmlviewer': No such file or directory`

`whereis qmlviewer` tells me that it's location is `/usr/bin/qmlviewer` so I try to run it with this absolute path, but I still get the same error

`qmlviewer: could not exec '/usr/lib/qt/bin/qmlviewer': No such file or directory`

Why is it still looking for that location ? How can I solve this ?

I should mention that I have tried `qtconfig` just for testing, and I still get the error, so this is a global Qt problem.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As said in the documentation : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-porting-qt5.html

> The qmlviewer tool provided for prototyping and testing QML
>   applications in Qt 4.x has been replaced with the qmlscene tool which
>   integrates with the new scenegraph features in Qt 5.

So using `qmlscence` all works.